# Java Overriding method issues

Tags: java, overriding

I am working on an assignment "Dessert Shoppe" and basically what I need to do is to create DessertItem subclasses `Candy`, `Cookie`, `IceCream`, `Sundae` and `Checkout`. I am also provided with DessertItem class & DessertShoppe and I am not allowed to modify them.

While I have created all these subclasses, when I run it on my TestCheckout.java , it will not work but rather display getName() in Sundae cannot override getName() in DessertItem.

```
public final String getName(){
                    ^
    overriden method is final.
```

I will provide you guys all the classes that I have made now.

```
public class DessertShoppe {

    public final static double TAX_RATE = 6.5;        // 6.5%
    public final static String STORE_NAME = "M & M Dessert Shoppe";
    public final static int MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE = 25;
    public final static int COST_WIDTH = 6;

    public static String cents2dollarsAndCents(int cents) {
        String s = "";

        if (cents < 0) {
            s += "-";
            cents *= -1;
        }

        int dollars = cents/100;
        cents = cents % 100;

        if (dollars > 0)
            s += dollars;

        s +=".";

        if (cents < 10)
            s += "0";

        s += cents;
        return s;
    } 
}


public abstract class DessertItem {

    protected String name;

    public DessertItem() {
        this("");
    }

    public DessertItem(String name) {
        if (name.length() <= DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE)
            this.name = name;
        else
            this.name = name.substring(0,DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE);
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public abstract int getCost();
}


public class Cookie extends DessertItem{

    protected double number;
    protected double pricePerDoze;

    public Cookie(String _n, double _ppd, int _number){
        super(_n);
        pricePerDoze = _ppd;
        number = _number;
    }

    public int getCost(){
        return  (int)Math.round(number / 12 * pricePerDoze);
    }
}


public class Candy extends DessertItem{

    protected double weight;
    protected double pricePerPound;

    public Candy(String _n, double _ppp, int _w){
        //using parent's constructor with name while storing its own properties
        super(_n);
        pricePerPound = _ppp;
        weight = _w;
    }

    public int getCost(){
        return  (int)Math.round(weight * pricePerPound);
    }
}


public class IceCream extends DessertItem{

    protected int cost;

    public IceCream(String _n, int _cost){
        super(_n);
        cost = _cost;
    }

    public int getCost(){
        return  cost;
    }
}


public class Sundae extends IceCream{

    protected String topName;
    protected int topCost;

    public Sundae(String _n0, int _cost0, String _n1, int _cost1){
        //put the icecream name in icecream while putting top name and cost in a separate property
        super(_n0, _cost0);
        topName = _n1;
        topCost = _cost1;
    }

    public final String getName(){
        //return both the icecream name and the topping name
        return name + " " + topName;
    }

    public int getCost(){
        //return the sum of the icecream and the topping
        return cost + topCost;
    }
}


public class Checkout{

    protected int size;
    protected DessertItem[] dessertItems;
    protected int amount;
    protected int sum;
    protected final double taxRate;

    Checkout(){
        size = 100;
        dessertItems = new DessertItem[size];
        amount = 0;
        sum = 0;
        taxRate = DessertShoppe.TAX_RATE;
    }

    public void enterItem(DessertItem d){
        dessertItems[amount] = d;
        amount ++;
    }

    public int numberOfItems(){
        return amount;
    }

    public int totalCost(){
        //make sum into zero, and calculate price from every item
        sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i ++){
            sum += dessertItems[i].getCost();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public int totalTax(){
        //use the totalCost method
        return (int)(Math.round(this.totalCost() * taxRate / 100));
    }

    public void clear(){
        //clear the array
        for(DessertItem d : dessertItems){
            d = null;
        }
        amount = 0;
        sum = 0;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = "Thank You! \n";

        result += DessertShoppe.STORE_NAME + "\n";

        result += "Purchased: ";

        String totalPay = DessertShoppe.cents2dollarsAndCents( totalCost()+totalTax() );
        if(totalPay.length() > DessertShoppe.COST_WIDTH){
            totalPay = totalPay.substring(0, DessertShoppe.COST_WIDTH);
        }
        result += "$" + totalPay;
        return result;
    }
}


public class TestCheckout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Checkout checkout = new Checkout();

        checkout.enterItem(new Candy("Peanut Butter Fudge", 2.25, 399));
        checkout.enterItem(new IceCream("Vanilla Ice Cream",105));
        checkout.enterItem(new Sundae("Choc. Chip Ice Cream",145, "Hot Fudge", 50));
        checkout.enterItem(new Cookie("Oatmeal Raisin Cookies", 4, 399));

        System.out.println("\nNumber of items: " + checkout.numberOfItems() + "\n");
        System.out.println("\nTotal cost: " + checkout.totalCost() + "\n");
        System.out.println("\nTotal tax: " + checkout.totalTax() + "\n");
        System.out.println("\nCost + Tax: " + (checkout.totalCost() + checkout.totalTax()) + "\n");
        System.out.println(checkout);

        checkout.clear();

        checkout.enterItem(new IceCream("Strawberry Ice Cream",145));
        checkout.enterItem(new Sundae("Vanilla Ice Cream",105, "Caramel", 50));
        checkout.enterItem(new Candy("Gummy Worms", 1.33, 89));
        checkout.enterItem(new Cookie("Chocolate Chip Cookies", 4, 399));
        checkout.enterItem(new Candy("Salt Water Taffy", 1.5, 209));
        checkout.enterItem(new Candy("Candy Corn",3.0, 109));

        System.out.println("\nNumber of items: " + checkout.numberOfItems() + "\n");
        System.out.println("\nTotal cost: " + checkout.totalCost() + "\n");
        System.out.println("\nTotal tax: " + checkout.totalTax() + "\n");
        System.out.println("\nCost + Tax: " + (checkout.totalCost() + checkout.totalTax()) + "\n");
        System.out.println(checkout);
    }
}
```

The expected output should be:

```
Number of items: 4


Total cost: 1331


Total tax: 87


Cost + Tax: 1418


M & M Dessert Shoppe
--------------------

2.25 lbs. @ 3.99 /lb.
Peanut Butter Fudge        8.98
Vanilla Ice Cream          1.05
Hot Fudge Sundae with
Choc. Chip Ice Cream       1.95
4 @ 3.99 /dz.
Oatmeal Raisin Cookies     1.33
Tax                         .87
Total Cost                14.18

Number of items: 6
```

Comment: Invoke `super(_n0 + " " + _n1, _cost0 + _cost1);` in the constructor of `Sundae`; then you don't need to override any methods. And for your own sake, give your variables better names.

Answer (score 2):

When a method is marked as final, it means that it cannot be overridden in a subclass.

Therefore, you need to use the `getName()` method as it stands, and figure out how to get the appropriate value into the `name` variable.

Luckily, there's a constructor in `IceCream` that does that, so all you need to do is pass into the constructor what you want `getName()` to return (and what you want `getCost()` to return):

```
public Sundae(String _n0, int _cost0, String _n1, int _cost1){
    super(_n1 + " Sundae with\n" + _n0, _cost0 + _cost1);
}
```

This way, your Sundae class doesn't need a `getName()` or a `getCost()` method.

Comment: so does this mean that for the Sundae class, all I need to write in that is  your answer?

Comment: I adapted your suggestion and compiled the tester. it does actually compile. However, the output rather displays different than the expected output.

Comment: In what way? Maybe the name parameter for the constructor should be `_n1 + " Sundae with\n" + _n0` ?

Comment: Edited to include this change.

Comment: The `toString()` method of your Checkout class doesn't have any code to print out individual items. You need to add some code there.

Comment: Now I am thinking how should I actually come up with the printing out of each individual item... how should I plan it ?

Comment: @Harry If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, the `final` modifier means that the method cannot be overridden by any of its subclasses.

There are two ways around this:

The first is to pass the arguments into the `Sundae` constructor as shown by Jason:

```
super(_n0 + " " + _n1, _cost0 + _cost1);
```

The second would be to utilize the fact that Sundae is a subclass of `IceCream`, which is a subclass of `DessertItem`. The `name` field is `protected`, meaning that you could directly access the field from the constructor.

Keep in mind, that with the second option, you will need to explicitly check to make sure that the `name` you provide is shorter than `DessertShoppe.MAX_ITEM_NAME_SIZE` to keep in line with that standard length.

The simpler and probably intended solution would be the first one, though both are valid.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help ! I have used Jason's method but hwen I compiled it and ran, it just displays expected output without those Dessert names and costs ... can you suggest why is that so ?